# mongoose#populate returns null in nested object inside array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a mongoDB database which is generated using a script that uses only the node.js mongoDB driver without mongoose. Later on, in the application, I want to use mongoose to load a document and have a reference be populated automatically; however, this only ever returns `null`.

Imagine a task which contains sub-items which each have a title and an assigned person. The assigned person, in this case, is the reference I want to have populated, so the reference lives in an object inside an array in the task schema.

The following code (requiring `npm install mongodb mongoose`) reproduces the problem (watch out, it destroys a local database named `test` if you have one already):

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

(async () => {
    // Step 1: Insert data. This is done using the mongodb driver without mongoose.
    const db = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
    await db.dropDatabase();
    await db.collection('persons').insertOne({ name: 'Joe' });

    const joe = await db.collection('persons').findOne({ name: 'Joe' });
    await db.collection('tasks').insertOne({ items: [{ title: 'Test', person: joe._id }] });

    await db.close();

    // ================
    // Step 2: Create the schemas and models.
    const PersonSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
    });
    const Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

    const TaskSchema = new Schema({
        items: [{
            title: String,
            person: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
        }],
    });
    const Task = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema);

    // ================
    // Step 3: Try to query the task and have it populated.
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
    mongoose.Promise = Promise;

    const myTask = await Task.findOne({}).populate('items.person');

    // :-( Unfortunately this prints only
    // { _id: "594283a5957e327d4896d135", items: [ { title: 'Test', person: null } ] }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myTask, null, 4));

    mongoose.connection.close();
})();
```

The *expected* output would be

```
{ _id: "594283a5957e327d4896d135", items: [ { title: 'Test', person: { _id: "594283a5957e327d4896d134", name: "Joe" } } ] }
```

I have verified that the two `_id`s actually match using mongo shell:

```
> db.persons.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("594283a5957e327d4896d134"), "name" : "Joe" }
> db.tasks.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("594283a5957e327d4896d135"), "items" : [ { "title" : "Test", "person" : ObjectId("594283a5957e327d4896d134") } ] }
```

What am I doing wrong when attempting to populate `person`? I am using mongoose 4.10.6 and mongodb 2.2.28.

Comment: *Note*: Adding `.exec()` after the `populate` call doesn't work either, neither does using a callback instead of `await`.

Comment: Also opened as [issue #5367](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5367) on mongoose now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem lies in the fact that the collection name mongoose automatically infers from the model `Person` is `people` and not `persons`.

The problem can be solved either by writing to the `people` collection in the first part or by forcing mongoose to use the collection name `persons`:

```
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema, 'persons');
```

mongoose plans to remove pluralization in the collection name anyway, see #1350 on Github.